# jQuery compare input value to a substring from div

Tags: jquery

I want to search in a div (id="results") from my page containting information from another website if the input value (id ="input") is a substring of a href inside the div.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    $("#Find").click( function(){
      $("#results").load("https://random website", function(){
       var $value = $("#input").val();
        $("#results").find("a").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is("[href*='$value']")) {
                return $value;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Okey, and what is your question?

Comment: My question is why is not working

Answer (score 0):

you should use foreach. Example;

```
$( "#input" ).each(function( index ) {
 var value = index.find("#input");
});
```

good work...

Comment: there should only be one input with id input - it's an id - not a class